"Bis Börs Söhne die Bälle erhuben" aus der Älteren Edda
Ganz am Anfang der Älteren Edda in der Übersetzung von Karl Simrock befindet sich diese Phrase:

Bis Börs Söhne die Bälle erhuben,
Sie die das mächtige Midgard schufen


In den Übersetzungen in andere Sprachen, die mir bekannt sind (Ukrainisch und Englisch), steht an der Stelle "Festland" anstatt "Bälle". Das ergibt Sinn - die Söhne Börs erhuben es vom Urozean und schufen dadurch die Erde, aber warum dann eine solche Wortwahl in der deutschen Übersetzung?
In meiner Auflage gibt es leider keine Kommentare zu dieser Stelle.

Originaltext: https://www.voluspa.org/voluspa1-5.htm

Disclaimer: Ich bin kein Experte für das Altnordische...
Kern des Problems scheint mir jedenfalls das Wort "bjöðum", wohl eine Pluralform von "bjǫð" bzw. "bjað" zu sein (siehe auch hier und hier). Nach den verfügbaren Online-Quellen ist die Bedeutung dieses Wortes ziemlich strittig, die Bedeutung "Land", "Erde" wird wohl eher aus dem Kontext ermittelt. Über die Etymologie wird diskutiert, hierzu müsste man in die Fachliteratur schauen (de Vries, Altnordisches Etymologisches Wörterbuch). Vor diesem Hintergrund würde ich annehmen, dass der Übersetzer sich zu einer freieren Wortwahl berechtigt sah. Ansatzpunkte wären für mich:

Grammatik: Erhaltung des Plural (wenn es sich tatsächlich um eine Pluralform handelt) --> "Welten" / "Erden"?
Klang: Wir reden hier über ein poetisches Werk und dessen "Nachdichtung" im Deutschen - ein Übersetzer könnte zur Erhaltung des Stabreims ein Wort suchen, das mit demselben Konsonanten wie das Original beginnt (hierzu schon die Antwort von David Vogt).

Das Grimm'sche Wörterbuch nennt als Bedeutung von "Ball" auch "Himmelskörper" (auch hier siehe die von David Vogt zitierten Übersetzungen).
Es finden sich noch skurrilere Ansätze, die "Bälle" ohne weitere Begründung als "Wälle" im Sinne von Ringwall, Befestigung lesen wollen (siehe die "Übersetzung" der Völuspa auf edda-online.com). Dieser Ansatz scheint am wenigsten überzeugend, auch mangels Quellen für eine solche Umlautung von W nach B (das Grimmsche Wörterbuch nennt weder unter "Ball" die Bedeutung "Wall" oder Beispiele hierfür, noch umgekehrt unter "Wall" für "Ball").

Für eine Übersetzung aus dem Jahr 1851 mit aktuellen wissenschaftlichen Wörterbüchern zu argumentieren, scheint mir nicht sehr zielführend. Welche Übersetzungshilfen Simrock benutzt haben kann, sollte theoretisch aus dem Verzeichnis seiner Bibliothek nachvollziehbar sein...allerdings ist das Internent Archive gerade nach einem DDOS-Angriff offline.

Es geht mir weniger darum, welche Hilfsmittel Simrock benutzt haben könnte, sondern darum, welches Wortspektrum nach aktuellem Kenntnisstand hinter "bjǫð" bzw. "bjað" steht. Hier erwarte ich mir von neuerer Literatur einen größeren Überblick, der je nach Sachfrage und Sachgebiet durchaus auch ins 19. Jahrhundert zurückreichen kann. Mit neuerer Literatur kann man also mehrere Fliegen mit einer Klappe erwischen. Was Simrock betrifft, kann man sowieso nur spekulieren.

Die Funktion der Übersetzung Bälle dürfte der Stabreim mit bis, Börs sein. Inhaltlich ist Bälle eine komische Wahl; soll man dabei an Gestirn, Himmelskörper denken?
Unter https://www.mimisbrunnr.info/cv-st-4-6 findet sich eine Gegenüberstellung verschiedener englischer Übersetzungen. Dort werden andere Stabreime hergestellt; mir gefallen diese zwei:

f. Hollander, 1928:
Was the land then lifted aloft by Bur's sons
who made Midgarth, the matchless earth;
shone from the south the sun on dry land,
on the ground then grew the greensward soft.
e. Bellows, 1923:
Then Bur's sons lifted the level land,
Mithgarth the mighty there they made;
The sun from the south warmed the stones of earth.
And green was the ground with growing leeks.

Eine alternative deutsche Übersetzung von Adolf Holtzmann lautet (via Google Books):

Ehe die Söhne des Burr die Himmelskörper erhoben,
sie, welche die große Welt schufen:
[…]


Das Wort "Bälle" für die erschaffenen runden Himmelskörper ist wahrscheinlich eine Gelegenheit die Anfangs-Konsonanten in jeder Zeile zu reimen: "Börs ... Bälle", "mächtige Midgard", "Sonne... Süden... Felsen", "Grund ..
grünte grüner...." und dann im 5ten Reim "Sonne Süden.. Gesellin", "rechten Hand Himmelsrosse", "Sonne... Sitz", "Mond... Macht" "Sterne ... Stätten."
